# When running git svn fetch --all, what does the --all option do?

Tags: git, fetch, git-svn

I've been researching how to use Git with an SVN repo, and there are many references that use the following command:

```
git svn fetch --all
```

However, I haven't found any reference that definitely tells me what `--all` does differently to `git svn fetch`, and I haven't noticed any difference when running `git svn fetch` with or without the `--all` option.  Is there any difference?

I am using Git 1.9.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--all` flag is mentioned but doesn't appear to be documented in the [`git-svn` man page](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e98671e5c2067a39759c8f08b79c260a9f0b2771). However, running

```
git log --grep="\-\-all" -- git-svn.perl
```

in a clone of the Git project's repo lists only two commits, [the older of which](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e98671e5c2067a39759c8f08b79c260a9f0b2771) describes `--all`:

> ```
> By default, fetch will fetch everything from its default
> [svn-remote]; if fetch [--all|-a] is specified, then it will
> fetch from all svn remotes.
> ```

The [most recent](https://github.com/git/git/commit/905f8b7dfc2c520b91f418ab0f2aecb1c371fbe4) of those two commits indicates that the short version (`-a`) was later dropped, and that `--fetch-all` was introduced as a synonym of `--all`:

> ```
> Note that the '-a' switch (short for --fetch-all/--all) has been
> removed as it conflicts with the non-svn 'git fetch'
> ```

(Further inspection reveals that those two commits their way into release `v1.5.1.1`, way before the version of Git you're using: `v1.9.5`.)